# Why does SSMS insert a ' TOP (100) PERCENT' into the view that I am trying to write and warn me that ORDER BY may not work?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a SQL View in SSMS.  I am using Views because they are easier to invoke from Power BI than Stored Procedures (especially when no parameters are needed).

I start by writing and testing a SQL SELECT query with an ORDER BY clause.

When I copy and paste my query in the New View:

1. SSMS adds a `TOP (100) PERCENT` to my SELECT statement.
2. Tells me that my `ORDER BY` clause (which works perfectly well in the SQL SELECT) may not work.
3. If you click the `Help` button on the dialog, you are taken to a Microsoft "Oops! No F1 help match was found" page.

   [image]

My questions are:

1. Is `TOP (100) PERCENT` not implied when it is left out of a SQL Select?
2. Why would a View based on a SQL Select statement not like ORDER BY clauses?

Comment: If you copy and paste a query without a `TOP (100) PERCENT` SSMS won't add a `TOP` to it... It would literally take the SQL you had before; which means the `TOP (100) PERCENT` was already there.

Comment: Don't use the visual view designers. Just paste `CREATE VIEW ... AS SELECT` into a new query window. But the `ORDER BY` needs to be on the `SELECT` from the view not inside the view anyway

Comment: The SQL string that I pasted did not include a TOP (100) PERCENT.  SSMS View Designer added a TOP (100) PERCENT to the SELECT.

Comment: Don't use the designer, like Martin said; it's just not good. Write your queries properly.

Comment: Could you clarify "ORDER BY needs to be on the SELECT from the view not inside the view"?

Comment: You can't naturally use an `ORDER BY` clause in a view (and for most purposes you shouldn't), have the hack to allow you to do so is to include `TOP (100) PERCENT` and then you are allowed an `ORDER BY`. My guess is SSMS is doing that for you, but I suggest thats not the best way to do it.

Comment: RE: "Could you clarify" Instead of `CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY C GO SELECT * FROM V` - you need to do  `CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT * FROM T GO SELECT * FROM V ORDER BY C` - the only place that an `ORDER BY` guarantees anything about the final order of the results is on the outer query. `SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT` is entirely optimised out and ignored anyway

Comment: So you either need to invoke a SQL query or proc rather than just select a view - or do the sorting in PowerBi

Comment: I did [try to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuJ6R.gif) the behaviour you speak of, but I couldn't.

Comment: Hi Larnu - my steps to reproduce are: (1) create a SQL query without a TOP (100) PERCENT with an ORDER BY (2) Copy the SQL Select (3) Right-click 'Views' in the Object Explorer (4) Past the copied SQL Select into the View Designer (5) Click Save.

Comment: It looks like I need to research calling a stored procedure from Power BI.

Comment: When [I add a sorted column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p3fN.gif) it adds a `TOP` too, @DougKimzey . I can't reproduce a scenario where the `TOP` is there with no `ORDER BY` nor vice versa. As I stated, if you are copying SQL *without* an `ORDER BY` SSMS won't add it; it was already there (maybe you just didn't notice it). For a `VIEW` to have an `ORDER BY` it *must* have a `TOP` (or `OFFSET` clause) as others have stated, however, a `TOP (100) PERCENT` with an `ORDER BY` would be effectively ignored, as the ordering should be done *outside* of the `VIEW`.

Comment: @Larnu https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WfxY.gif

Comment: @MartinSmith  and SSMS added the `TOP (100)` as soon as the `ORDER BY` was there, before you have a chance to copy it, so it further evidences that it *was* there when the OP copied it.

Comment: They have never claimed anything different. "I start by writing and testing a SQL SELECT query **with an ORDER BY clause**. When I copy and paste my query in the New View:"

Comment: [*"The SQL string that I pasted did not include a TOP (100) PERCENT"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839627/why-does-ssms-insert-a-top-100-percent-into-the-view-that-i-am-trying-to-wr?noredirect=1#comment125233543_70839627) @MartinSmith .

Comment: yes it didn't include a **TOP 100 PERCENT** - SSMS view designer adds that itself if you paste in SQL text with an `ORDER BY` (or where the SQL text is edited to add an `ORDER BY`)

Comment: I am going to see if I can call a stored procedure from Power BI (assuming a SQL Select in an sp can have an ORDER BY...).  Views come in to Power BI - but are not reliably ordered.     I can set the order of a view in Power BI (but this will cost performance..)  I thought Views were a way to package complex SQL Selects.  I will have to research when and why views are used.  Thanks to all...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a view with ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187676/create-a-view-with-order-by-clause)

Answer (score 2):

SQL views to not support ORDER BY. For more detail on this, see these other posts:

[Create a view with ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187676/create-a-view-with-order-by-clause/15188437#15188437)

[Possible to have an OrderBy in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227746/possible-to-have-an-orderby-in-a-view/4227793#4227793)

[Order BY is not supported in view in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888472)

[Why use Select Top 100 Percent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622878/why-use-select-top-100-percent)

---

As @Martin Smith said, your options are one of the following:

1. Put the ORDER BY in a query that references the view.

```
SELECT * FROM ViewName ORDER BY [...]
```

2. Do the ordering in the Power Query Editor. If you don't have any steps before this sort that break [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding), this should be translated into a native SQL query that gets evaluated on the SQL Server.

I recommend the latter since further steps can also potentially be folded in as well. Specifying your own query does not support query folding.

Comment: Hi Alexis - I tried the SELECT * FROM ViewName ORDER BY [...] in the Power Query Editor and got the same warning message in Power Query Editor as I get for a View in SSMS with an ORDER BY.  I think the only thing to do is try a stored proc.

Comment: Make sure that the view does not have the `TOP (100) PERCENT` or `ORDER BY` parts in it, just a plain `SELECT ... FROM` query.

Comment: It does not.  It is a plain SELECT ... FROM.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. I suggest using my second suggestion.

Comment: The view is a plain SELECT ... FROM.  No `TOP (100) PERCENT` or `ORDER BY` parts.  I added a new query in Power Query Editor that is a SELECT * FROM UnorderedView ORDER BY [...].  Power Query Editor returned an unordered bag of rows and displayed the same error that you get in MSSM when you try to create a View with an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I verified the View by having MSSM create a DROP...CREATE script for the view.  The `SELECT` contains no `TOP (100) PERCENT` and no `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It does not do that for me when I test it on my computer. Does Refresh Preview help at all? If not, do you get the same error if you just use `SELECT * FROM ViewName` as the query?